# Custom field doesn't appear in sugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, custom-fields

I have created a custom field **sugarfield_ast_rec_link_c.php** in **custom/Extension/modules/Calls/Ext/Vardefs** with such content:
`

```
<?php
$dictionary['Calls']['fields']['ast_rec_link_c'] = array
('name' => 'ast_rec_link_c',
 'vname' => 'LBL_AST_REC_LINK_C',
 'type' => 'varchar',
 'len' => '255',
 'source' => 'non-db',
 'function' => array('name'=>'getRecordLink',
                     'returns'=>'html',
                     'include'=>'custom/modules/Calls/CustomLogic.php')
);

?>
```

`
Also aded language file in **custom/Extension/modules/Calls/Ext/Language**. After quick repair my custom field doesn't appear in Studio -> Calls -> Fields. So I can't put it on views. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

You should change

```
<?php
$dictionary['Calls']['fields']['ast_rec_link_c'] = array(...);
```

to

```
<?php
$dictionary['Call']['fields']['ast_rec_link_c'] = array(...);
```

Remember you should always use bean name (not module one!) as a $dictionary array key while defining new custom fields.
In my opinion best way to check if everything is OK with your custom vardefs is to compare your own ones with existing in `cache/modules/<module_name>/BEAN_NAMEvardefs.php`

Comment: Thanks, but I have already realised it myself :) Strange thing is that I can find my custom field only in list view, but not in detatil view etc.. And even in the list view the field appears empty despite the function getRecordLink, which simply returns '<a href="ya.ru">ya.ru</a>'